# C++ wrapper for use in C#. Using private class as parameter

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, wrapper

I'm creating a .dll for use in C#, but I'm having trouble understanding wrappers.

Let's say that my original C++ code has a function that looks like this:

```
void classB::do_something(classA& parameterA);
```

In my C++ wrapper for classA, the class pointer is private:

```
public ref class classAwrapper{
    private:
        classA* classapointer;
    public:
        ...
}
```

Since I can't do the following,

```
void classBwrapper::do_something(classAwrapper parameterA){
    classbpointer->do_something(parameterA->classapointer);
}
```

is there anything I can do?

Comment: classapointer needs to be *internal*, not private.

Answer (score 0):

Add a friend.

Write:

```
private:
    friend class classBwrapper;
    classA * classapointer;
```

instead of

```
private:
    classA * classapointer;
```

You can essentially add classes and functions to a 'white-list' using the `friend` keyword. `classapointer` won't be accessible to anything but `classBwrapper`

Comment: Is classAwrapper in c++ or c#?

Comment: Yeah I agree with Hans. I think the internal keyword is what you want instead of private. You may have to mess with the CLI assemblies to get the private/internal pointer to be accessible. The only other thing I can think of (I'm pulling from my C background) is to pretend that `classAwrapper` is a struct and use memory offsets to get `classapointer`.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed Hans until a few minutes ago. internal sounds exactly like what I need. The online tutorials always used private for some reason. Thanks, both of you.